# Using CONCATENATE on minutes converts them to decimal numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I am trying to CONCATENATE cells that contain total minutes into one cell. When using this formula,

```
=CONCATENATE(INDEX(DTOOLBackTbl,MATCH(SelectedDate,DTOOLBackTbl[Date],FALSE),MATCH(R5&" AM Time",DTOOLBackTbl[#Headers],FALSE))," \ ",INDEX(DTOOLBackTbl,MATCH(SelectedDate,DTOOLBackTbl[Date],FALSE),MATCH(R5&" PM Time",DTOOLBackTbl[#Headers],FALSE))," \ ",INDEX(DTOOLBackTbl,MATCH(SelectedDate,DTOOLBackTbl[Date],FALSE),MATCH(R5&" NIGHTS Time",DTOOLBackTbl[#Headers],FALSE)))
```

it returns decimal numbers.

I have tried formatting the cells to custom `[m]` to no avail.

Can this be done using CONCATENATE  or is there another way?

Comment: Hey there, the one which is within `CONCATENATE()` Functions needs to be wrapped within `TEXT()` Function it is obvious going to return in decimal since in Excel date and times are stored as numbers, the integer part represents the dates while the time represents the decimals

Comment: So that said the formula needs to be like if am not wrong then, `=CONCATENATE(TEXT(INDEX(DTOOLBackTbl,MATCH(SelectedDate,DTOOLBackTbl[Date],FALSE),MATCH(R5&" AM Time",DTOOLBackTbl[#Headers],FALSE))," \ ",INDEX(DTOOLBackTbl,MATCH(SelectedDate,DTOOLBackTbl[Date],FALSE),MATCH(R5&" PM Time",DTOOLBackTbl[#Headers],FALSE))," \ ",INDEX(DTOOLBackTbl,MATCH(SelectedDate,DTOOLBackTbl[Date],FALSE),MATCH(R5&" NIGHTS Time",DTOOLBackTbl[#Headers],FALSE)),"[m]"))`

Comment: Yes, thank you. Tweaked a bit from above to get working

Comment: Great, or you can wrap the whole of `CONCATENATE()` within a `TEXT()` Function so `TEXT(Your_Formula,"[m]")`